# Mysql messaging app query for one to one message order by latest

Tags: mysql

**Table strucutre**

```
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mail_box` (
      `msg_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `sender_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `receiver_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `message` text NOT NULL,
      `date` timestamp NOT NULL,
      `attachment` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
      `status` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`msg_id`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=10 ;

    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL
     ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Need the query for one to one conversation

---

### **Query I tried for one to one messages order by latest**

```
SELECT usr.name as Receiver,usr1.name as Sender, message,date
FROM mail_box 
JOIN users as usr on usr.id = receiver_id 
JOIN users as usr1 on usr1.id = sender_id 
AND receiver_id IN (1,2)
AND sender_id IN (1,2)
ORDER BY date DESC
```

This query is working. Is there any alternative query for the same result.

Comment: show us your dulicate result

Comment: pls show some sample data as well that produces the duplicate results.